# Props in Vue 3 App and Typescript breaking the build

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am using Vue 3 + Vite + TS and am trying to build a single-spa MF.
For instance, I need to pass a prop to one of the micro frontends. When I declare the props in the App.vue, however, the build fails

```
src/main.ts:24:16 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'DefineComponent<__VLS_TypePropsToRuntimeProps<Props>, {}, unknown, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, ... 4 more ..., {}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DefineComponent<__VLS_TypePropsToRuntimeProps<Props>, {}, {}, ComputedOptions, MethodOptions, ComponentOptionsMixin, ... 5 more ..., {}>'.
      Type 'DefineComponent<__VLS_TypePropsToRuntimeProps<Props>, {}, unknown, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, ... 4 more ..., {}>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentPublicInstanceConstructor<{ $: ComponentInternalInstance; $data: {}; $props: Partial<{}> & Omit<Readonly<{ authToken?: unknown; } & { authToken: string; } & {}> & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps, never>; ... 10 more ...; $watch(source: string | Function, cb: Function, options?: Wat...'.
        Type '{ $: import("<MY_DIR>/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core").ComponentInternalInstance; $data: {}; $props: Partial<{}> & Omit<Readonly<...> & import("<MY_DIR>/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core").VNodeProps & import("<MY_DIR>/no...' is not assignable to type '{ $: import("<MY_DIR>/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core").ComponentInternalInstance; $data: {}; $props: Partial<{}> & Omit<Readonly<...> & import("<MY_DIR>/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core").VNodeProps & import("<MY_DIR>/no...'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
          Type '{ $: import("<MY_DIR>/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core").ComponentInternalInstance; $data: {}; $props: Partial<{}> & Omit<Readonly<...> & import("<MY_DIR>/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core").VNodeProps & import("<MY_DIR>/no...' is not assignable to type '{ $: import("<MY_DIR>/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core").ComponentInternalInstance; $data: {}; $props: Partial<{}> & Omit<Readonly<{ ...; } & ... 1 more ... & {}> & import("<MY_DIR>/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core").VNodeProps & import("/User...'.
            Types of property '$options' are incompatible.
              Type 'ComponentOptionsBase<Readonly<{ authToken?: unknown; } & { authToken: string; } & {}>, {}, unknown, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, Record<...>, string, {}> & MergedComponentOptionsOverride' is not assignable to type 'ComponentOptionsBase<Readonly<{ authToken?: unknown; } & { authToken: string; } & {}>, {}, {}, ComputedOptions, MethodOptions, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, {}, string, {}> & MergedComponentOptionsOverride'.
                Type 'ComponentOptionsBase<Readonly<{ authToken?: unknown; } & { authToken: string; } & {}>, {}, unknown, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, Record<...>, string, {}> & MergedComponentOptionsOverride' is not assignable to type 'ComponentOptionsBase<Readonly<{ authToken?: unknown; } & { authToken: string; } & {}>, {}, {}, ComputedOptions, MethodOptions, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, {}, string, {}>'.
                  Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
                    Type '((this: CreateComponentPublicInstance<...>, vm: CreateComponentPublicInstance<Readonly<{ authToken?: unknown; } & { authToken: string; } & {}>, {}, {}, {}, MethodOptions, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, ... 10 more ..., {}>) => unknown) | undefined' is not assignable to type '((this: CreateComponentPublicInstance<...>, vm: CreateComponentPublicInstance<Readonly<{ authToken?: unknown; } & { authToken: string; } & {}>, {}, {}, {}, MethodOptions, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, ... 10 more ..., {}>) => {}) | undefined'.
                      Type '(this: CreateComponentPublicInstance<...>, vm: CreateComponentPublicInstance<Readonly<{ authToken?: unknown; } & { authToken: string; } & {}>, {}, {}, {}, MethodOptions, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, ... 10 more ..., {}>) => unknown' is not assignable to type '(this: CreateComponentPublicInstance<...>, vm: CreateComponentPublicInstance<Readonly<{ authToken?: unknown; } & { authToken: string; } & {}>, {}, {}, {}, MethodOptions, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, ... 10 more ..., {}>) => {}'.
                        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{}'.

24       return h(App, {
                  ~~~

  node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.d.ts:948:25
    948 export declare function h<P>(type: DefineComponent<P>, props?: (RawProps & P) | ({} extends P ? null : never), children?: RawChildren | RawSlots): VNode;
                                ~
    The last overload is declared here.
```

The code I added to App.vue that breaks everything

```
interface Props {
  authToken: string;
}

const props = defineProps<Props>();
```

Comment: You provided undefined as an argument, which certainly doesn't conform `Props` type. Consider inferring the type from actual props object to not write the same thing twice

Comment: Which TypeScript version are you using?

Comment: I am using Typescript 4.4.4